# Inspecting a caught error in a React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working with a React Native app in a dev environment and am running into an error whereby a toast is shown after I try to upload a file. The code is similar to the following:

```
function* onUploadPrompt(action: Action): Saga<*> {

  try {
    yield put(ProfileCertificateUpload.uploadEnd());
  } catch (err) {
    debugger;
    // if upload fails show a toast to user so they may retry
    yield put(Toast.showNegative(str.uploadFail()));
    yield put(ProfileCertificateUpload.uploadEnd());
  }
}
```

Note that I've set a `debugger` breakpoint in the `catch` block. If I stop the package manager and start it again (using `yarn start`) and go through the flow to trigger the error, I hit the breakpoint:

[image]

What puzzles me is that I don't see `err` anywhere; I can't inspect it. Shouldn't the `err` error variable be in scope where I set my breakpoint, so that I can have a look at the error and learn more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of debugger, put console.log(‘error:’, err); and check your console to see what the error actually is.